# Java script Regex- Validate URL

Tags: javascript, regex

When a user submits URL,i've to validate the URL.

For Eg:Whether he has put HTTP/HTTPS,.com,.www

I tried this regex but how to add http/https

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try my updated answer and let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkValid(){
  return /((http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)|)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(checkValid.arguments[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  You can test it here.  http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1854

```
^(http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$
```

Comment: `[2-4]`? In 2012, *eleven years* after `.travel` and `.museum`, and two years after IDNs went live? Srsly?

Comment: Worked just fine for 'http://www.yoursite.travel'. You should test it yourself before downvoting.

Comment: @user1263374 - have you tried this one?  Despite Piskvor's comments, it worked for every URL I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this,

```
  function isValidURL(url){ 
    var RegExp = /^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/; 
    if(RegExp.test(url)){ 
        return true; 
    }else{ 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: :I used second function,i inputted http://www.google.com but it is showing as error.

Comment: `is_valid_url()` is goint to break (even worse than it's broken now) in a few months. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.in#Internationalized_domain_names_and_country_codes